# Проблема с OnTriggerEnter в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Sword"){
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
        
    }
```

У меня есть объект с тегом Sword. И если враг его касается(скрипт весит на нём), то он и объект с тегом должен исчезнуть. Но этого не происходит.

Comment: Кстати, а почему вы отменили мою правку с тегом Unity3D? Данный тег является обобщающим для всех вопросов, связанный с юнити, вне зависимости от того, 2Д игра или 3Д. А вот если игра 2Д, то дополнительно, по желанию можно добавить тег Untiy2D. Однако в вашем вопросе 2Д не упоминается.

Comment: поменяйте местами уничтожение "gameObject" и "other.gameObject"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это может происходить потому, что ваш код не срабатывает.
Помимо того, что он может не срабатывать из-за того, что тег у вас не Sword, причиной также может быть то, что OnTriggerEnter() срабатывает ТОЛЬКО ЕСЛИ:

1. На обоих объектах есть Collider
2. Один и только один помечен как триггер
3. Хотя бы на одном есть Rigidbody

Из [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html):
`Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component.`

Comment: Все условия, которые вы написали у меня соблюдены.

Comment: А если вы попытаетесь принтом вывести какую-либо строку в функции OnTriggerEnter, то эта строка выводится?

Comment: Кстати, судя по тому, что вы отменили мою правку с Unity3D могу предположить, что у вас игра в 2D и коллайдеры соотвтственно тоже 2D: типа BoxColldier2D, CircleCollider2D. Я надеюсь, вы знаете, что для столкновение 2D объектов служит функция OnTriggerEnter2D, а не просто OnTriggerEnter?

Comment: Спасибо что рассказали. Я новичок в юнити. Спасибо вам огромное.

Comment: Надо тегать через собачку собеседника, чтобы он увидел ваше сообщение в уведомлениях.

Comment: Можно не тегать только автора поста, то есть вас в данном случае. Автора вопроса можно не тегать, если вы пишете комментарий под самим вопросом. То есть это относится не к автору вопроса, а автору поста, под которым комментарий.

Comment: @farkon00 Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав галочку. Это значит, что ответ получен, а вопрос решен.